# Simple proof that W(3,3)=27?

Tags: ramsey-theory

I was wondering that if there exists a simple proof that the van der Warden's number W(3,3) (the smallest positive integer $n$ such that any 3-coloring of the set $\{1, 2, ..., n\}$ has a monochromatic 3-AP) equals 27. 
Also, it would be great if someone can present me a counterexample for $n=26$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The complete list of length-26 examples is:

```
    AABBAABCBCCACAABABBCACCBCB
    AABBCAACACBBCCBBCACAACBBAA
    AABCBAACACBBCCBBCACAABCBAA
    AACBCAABABCCBBCCBABAACBCAA
    AACCAACBCBBABAACACCBABBCBC
    AACCBAABABCCBBCCBABAABCCAA
    ABAABABCCBBCCBABAABCCAACAC
    ABABBAACBBCBCAACCAACBCBBCA
```

not counting relabeling of the colors. (So there are 48 examples in all.)

I don't know of any proof that 27 is exact, other than a suitably-pruned exhaustive search.

I have source code that I wrote about 25 years ago that does the search, plus some discussion, [on my blog](http://blog.plover.com/prog/van-der-waerden.html). The code took a couple of days to run when I first wrote it, but to run it now is very quick.

Comment: That is very interesting! Thank you very much.

Comment: I don't think you should be so quick to accept the answer, particularly since it's incomplete. What if there *is* a simple proof that 27 is exact, and I don't know it, and the person who does know it skips over this question because you accepted an answer already?  If I were you, I'd un-accept the answer, and wait a couple of days to see what else turns up.

Comment: This can't be the correct list of examples, since there shouldn't be any strings that begin with `AAC`.  (I should have exchanged the labels `B` and `C`.)  Also if you reverse the first string `AABBAABCBCCACAABABBCACCBCB`, and then relabel `B`→`A`, `C`→`B`, `A`→`C`, you get `ABABBCBAACACCBCBBABACCAACC`, which should be on the list but is not.  I will try to fix this soon.